# #define argument stringized but to a wide string L" instead of "

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, stringification

I need to stringify a `#define` argument to a wide string.

So while

```
#define c(x) x,#x
```

used as:

```
{c(maria),0,false},
```

gives:

```
{maria,"maria",0,false} // maria is a member of an enum.
```

I don't know how to do the same but creating a wide string.

What I mean is instead of having `"maria"` having `L"maria"`

Comment: Please people answer me: Is not this kind of question should tagged as `C` instead of `C++`? Even if C++ is compatible with C, this practice (Macros and stringficing) is not good C++ at all. Its C

Comment: @Manu343726 No, C++ is not 100% compatible with C, even at the preprocessing phase.

Comment: @Manu343726: Sometimes it's necessary though.

Comment: @hvd I know, thats why I'm asking. I always try to treat C and C++ as different languages, and this kind of questions tagged as C++ don't help

Comment: @Oli ok, so `c` and `c++` is more proper, I think.

Comment: @Manu343726 If the OP wants an answer that works in C++, he should tag the question as C++. If the question is tagged as C, and the OP gets an answer that only works in C, not in C++, how does that help anybody?

Comment: @Manu343726 If you can find a solution for this particular question that doesn't involve macros, go ahead, post it! Millions of devs around the planet will adore you. If you cannot, don't claim that macros should not be used.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
#define c(x) x,L###x
```

The `##` concatenation is necessary to combine the `L` and the quoted string into a single preprocessing token (as the `L` is part of a *string-literal* token).

```
#define c(x) x,L###x
c(Hello)
```

Sticking this through the preprocessor (with `clang++ -E test.cpp`) gives:

```
Hello,L"Hello"
```

Comment: What whitespace? Mine works perfectly in visual studio, while `L ""` (with whitespace) doesn't work. So it doesn't create any.

Comment: The concatenation is not required to avoid having whitespace, but it is required to avoid treating `L` and the string literal as separate tokens (in a conforming implementation, anyway).

Comment: @user2345215 With clang I get `Hello,L "Hello"` without the concatenation. I've been looking for the reason why.

Comment: @sftrabbit In standard C++, there is no way to see the preprocessor output other than by stringizing it, and if you try that, you'll find that there is no whitespace. clang (and gcc, and others) output a space anyway to ensure that the tokens don't get concatenated incorrectly.

Comment: @hvd That makes sense. Corrected my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
#define c(x) x,L#x
```

EDIT: Apparently, this works only in Visual Studio. So you should go with `L###x` as others have suggested.